# find and replace quotes inside quotes with regular expression in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a very large JSON file with almost 30000 records. 
One record looks something like this:

```
{
  "adlibJSON": {
    "recordList": {
      "record": [
        {
          "@attributes": {
            "priref": "4372",
            "created": "2011-12-09T23:09:57",
            "modification": "2012-08-11T17:07:51",
            "selected": "False"
          },
          "acquisition.date": [
            "1954"
          ],
          "documentation.title": [
            "A lot of text with a lot of extra double quotes like "this" and "this""
          ] ... ...
```

The problem is that there are a lot of values with extra double quotes in it. This can be 1 double quote, but also 2 or 3 extra double quotes. See the value of `"documentation.title"` in my example.

How do i find all these quotes and replace them with regular expression. 
I use sublime text 2 to do my regular expression, but i don't know how to solve this specific problem.

Comment: Do you have to do this in the client side (I mean by Javascript)? Do you have the option of processing this in PHP? Also, you can write a recursive function to check the value(s) of each variable and replace the quotes with whatever you want.

Comment: how would a function like that look?

Comment: Do you have access (to modify) the script that is creating this JSON file?

Comment: no i can't acces that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples:

These have the following requirements:

- Values do not start with a comma, a colon, a closing braces or a whitespace.

Otherwise you have to improve it. The second one even allows values to start with a whitespace, but may also have some other side-effects ...

Example 1:

```
\"[A-Za-z0-9][^"]+\"\s*[^,:}\s]
```

Example 2:

```
\"([A-Za-z0-9\s][^"]+\"\s*[^,:\]}\s]){2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a chance to use PHP and if you can ensure that the JSON file will be provided with PRETTY_PRINT (lines separated like in your example output)… You can create a PHP file to which you will send the file name and get the corrected output. Here's an example.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$file = @trim($_GET['file']);
if (empty($file) || ($contents = @file_get_contents($file)) === FALSE) {
    // handle errors here
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Invalid file!'));
    exit;
}
function escapeQuotes($m) {
    return $m[1].$m[2].preg_replace('~(?<!\\\\)(?<!^)"(?!$)~','\\"',$m[3]).$m[4];
}
$res = preg_replace_callback(
    '~^(\s*)("[^"\s]+"\s*:\s*)?(".*")(,?\s*)$~m',
    'escapeQuotes',$contents
);
echo json_encode(json_decode($res,true));
```