# Regular Expression for selectively escaping characters inside JSON values

Tags: java, regex, json, servlets

I have JSON that can potentially have double quotes inside some of the values. My parser correctly interprets these values as the end of the value, when in reality it is just a double quote the user typed in and is part of the value itself. Ideally this would be escaped on the client side, but in this situation that is not possible. As a result I need to correct this on the server side. The server code is a java servlet, and I believe the easiest way is to use a regex to find the field that potentially could have this issue and replace any quotes inside of it. This is somewhat tricky as I have to distinguish between the legitimate quote at the end of the value, and an erroneous quote inside the value itself.

Sample JSON:

```
{
 "question" : "some question",
 "answer"   : "some answer that might have "quotes" in it.",
 "name"     : "some name"
}
```

EDIT:
This field may in fact be last in certain situations, in which case it will be followed by a closing brace.

I have struggled to create a regex to find quotes meeting the above requirements. So my question is:

What is the regex, if any, that will find the quotes meeting the above criteria? If there isn't one, how can this problem be solved another way?

One additional detail: There may or may not be multiple JSON arrays in the same string, although I can split those apart into an array of strings.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14482136/1426079

Comment: Bummer that this can't be handled on the client side, the correct way. That also seems like a security concern to allow quotes into the data. I would really apply pressure to whoever's in charge of that clietn code if I were in that situation.

Comment: Brinnis, that question and answer are helpful but do not solve the problem in all cases which is logically possible in this case as it is limited to one field that is never last. Scott, without going into details in this case that is not possible.

Comment: It is not exactly the same. There are additional fields both before and after the three listed, and there are not newlines in the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the answer string first and then escape the double quotes.

Consider this code:

```
Sting str = "{\"question\" : \"some question\", \"answer\": " + 
  "\"some answer that might have \"quotes\" in it.\", \"name\": \"some name\"}";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile
    ("(?s)(?i)(\"answer\"\\s*:\\s*\")(.+?)(?=\"\\s*[,}])").matcher(str);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buf, m.group(1) + m.group(2).replace("\"", "\\\\\""));
}
m.appendTail(buf);  
System.out.printf("%s%n", buf);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
{
   "question" : "some question",
   "answer": "some answer that might have \"quotes\" in it.",
   "name": "some name"
}
```

Comment: Tahnks anubhava. This answers the original question I had, so I'll mark your answer as correct, however I have since determined that the field may in fact be last. Can you modify your solution to solve that case as well?

Comment: John: Ok modified it accordingly, pls check.

Comment: anubhava, this works great and hopefully will serve as an example of using the matcher class for others with similar problems. thank you.